# Eval only works if I define scope outside of the call

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

I have the following simplified code:

```
scope = locals()
for batch in stream:
     for row in batch.results:
          writer.writerow([eval(pf, scope) for pf in process_fields])
```

It saves in a `csv` the content of the different fields of the `row` object (`GoogleAdsRow` object)

It works fine, but it fails if I do not use `scope` variable, but `locals()` function directly:

```
for batch in stream:
     for row in batch.results:
          writer.writerow([eval(pf, locals()) for pf in process_fields])
```

It returns:

`NameError: name 'account' is not defined` where `account` is one of the `process_fields`.
So I assume it's because the `eval` function do not find the variable, but I do not understand why such an small change create that issue.

Comment: specifically, do you assign something to it after `scope = locals()` ?

Comment: List comprehensions have their own scope, so you are calling `locals` in the wrong scope in the second example.

Comment: @wjandrea pf is defined in the code above... it's in the list comprehension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a small change. In the code you show, there are *two* scopes:

1. Whatever scope the loop is in.
2. The scope created by the list comprehension.

In your first example, you call `locals` in the first scope.

In your second example, you call `locals` in the second scope.

Comment: Thanks @chepner Didn't know those different scopes.

Comment: It was a change from Python 2 to Python 3, and not one of the more well publicized ones.